# Nginx restricting access by machine name instead of IP address

Tags: nginx, ip

I use nginx with simple auth rules such as the following:

```
location /api {
    #...
    deny  192.168.1.2;
    allow 10.128.99.1;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

This works great, but sometimes a users IP changes, then I have to update the nginx.conf file with the new IP.  Is there any way to use machine name instead, such as the following:

```
location /api {
    #...
    deny  192.168.1.2;
    allow MachineName;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

I tried that, but nginx gave an error when I tried to start the service.  I can use ping to look up the IP, but I am just trying to automate the process.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Nginx HTTP rDNS module](https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns) which allows doing just the very thing you're asking about:

> This module allows to make a reverse DNS (rDNS) lookup for incoming connection and provides simple access control of incoming hostname by allow/deny rules

The only downside is that you'll [have to disable HTTP/1.1 keepalive](https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns/issues/20) due to outstanding bug, which was never fixed.

Installation on CentOS systems (6, 7 and 8) can be done using [*commercial* GetPageSpeed repository](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-extras) (requires subscription):

```
sudo yum -y install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-latest.rpm
sudo yum -y install nginx-module-rdns
```